# Renaming Data Frame Column Names using Partial Matching

Tags: r

If I have the code at the bottom of the post, how can I replace the column names of df1 with the second column of df2 using partial matching of df2's first column? The output should look like df3. The entirety of my data frame is filled with many other names besides .length (i.e. CS1.1.width, CS2.12.height, etc), but the CS#.#. always remains in the name.

I then need to remove the ".length" from the colnames.

I have tried using pmatch below for the first part of the question, but the output is not correct.

```
names(df1) <- df2$new[pmatch(names(df1), df2$partial_atch)]
```

How would I go about this? Thanks.

```
old <- c("CS1.1.length", "CS1.7.length", "CS1.10.length", "CS1.12.length", "CS2.4.length", "CS2.6.length", "CS2.9.length", "CS2.11.length", "CS1.1.height")
df1 <- data.frame()
for (k in old) df1[[k]] <- as.character()


new <- c("Bob", "Alex", "Gary", "Taylor", "Tom", "John", "Pat", "Mary")
partial_match <- c("CS1.1", "CS1.7", "CS1.10", "CS1.12", "CS2.4", "CS2.6", "CS2.9", "CS2.11")
df2 <- data.frame(Partial_Match = partial_match, Name = new)


new1 <- c("Bob.length", "Alex.length", "Gary.length", "Taylor.length", "Tom.length", "John.length", "Pat.length", "Mary.length", "Bob.height")
df3 <- data.frame()
for (k in new) df3[[k]] <- as.character()
```

Edit: The number of columns in df1 is greater than the number of elements in partial_match, so added an additional column in df1 as example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with `str_replace` from the `stringi` package:

This works because you can use a vector of `pattern =` to replace with a matching `replacement =`.

We need to `paste` on the trailing `.` because this prevents `CS1.1` replacing `CS1.11` and `CS1.10`.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_regex(names(df1),
                       pattern = paste0(as.character(df2$Partial_Match),"\\."),
                       replacement = paste0(as.character(df2$Name),"\\."),
                       vectorize_all = FALSE)
#[1] "Bob.length"    "Alex.length"   "Gary.length"   "Taylor.length" "Tom.length"    "John.length"   "Pat.length"   
#[8] "Mary.length"
```

Comment: This only works if the number of columns in df1 is the same as the elements of Partial_Match. What is the solution if the number of columns in df1 is greater than the number of elements in Partial_Match?

Comment: You're right, here's a better approach with `stringi`

Comment: Thank for the help mate!